# retrieve certain time from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns having datetime datatype.

```
startDateTime             | endDateTime
-----------------------------------------------------
2016/01/01 13:10:50.000   |2016/03/01 15:20:21.222
```

I tried to retrieve the output from above table in total no of hrs passed from range 10:00:00.000 to 16:59:59.999 from startDateTime to endDateTime. but it didn't worked.

Comment: what did you try? and is it mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: 10AM to 4AM? You need to explain more. This would span multiple days. What would be the expected output

Comment: @dbajtr sql-server

Comment: Show your query that you tried.

Comment: Ok, so 1649... but that doesn't explain the spanning of days. What if it was on the same day? Should both be returned. Explain more... be descriptive :) Does both startDate and EndDate need to fall in that range or only one?

Comment: @scsimon It does includes FromDate to ToDate. And hours from 10-4:59 should only be included

Comment: Do you mean that you that time span for each record in the table ? (in the limits or 10-16:59 Or that you want to sum the times of all the rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an aggregation with limits.  It would be nice if SQL Server had a `greatest()`/`least()` function.  But alas, no.  So:

```
select sum(datediff(hour,
                    (case when convert(time, startDateTime) < '10:00:00' 
                          then '10:00:00'
                          when convert(time, startDateTime) > '17:00:00'
                          then '17:00:00'
                          else convert(time, startDateTime)
                     end), 
                    (case when convert(time, endDateTime) < '10:00:00' 
                          then '10:00:00'
                          when convert(time, endDateTime) > '17:00:00'
                          then '17:00:00'
                          else convert(time, endDateTime)
                     end)
                    )) as diffhours
```

I would be inclined to do the difference in minutes and then convert to hours at the end:

```
select sum(datediff(minute,
                    (case when convert(time, startDateTime) < '10:00:00' 
                          then '10:00:00'
                          when convert(time, startDateTime) > '17:00:00'
                          then '17:00:00'
                          else convert(time, startDateTime)
                     end), 
                    (case when convert(time, endDateTime) < '10:00:00' 
                          then '10:00:00'
                          when convert(time, endDateTime) > '17:00:00'
                          then '17:00:00'
                          else convert(time, endDateTime)
                     end)
                    )) as diffminutes
```

You would then decide if you want to round or truncate for the conversion to hours.

Answer (score 0):

If both startDateTime and endDateTime must be inclusive, **without respect to the date**, then you just need to check the time portion.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
   cast(startDateTime as Time) between '10:00:00.000' and '16:59:59.999'
   and
   cast(endDateTime as Time) between '10:00:00.000' and '16:59:59.999'
```

If only startDateTime **or** endDateTime need to fall in the range, then you can use an `or`

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE 
   cast(startDateTime as Time) between '10:00:00.000' and '16:59:59.999'
   and
   cast(endDateTime as Time) between '10:00:00.000' and '16:59:59.999'
```